# Хорошо ли сохранять промежуточное значение в переменную, если строчка уже длинная?

Tags: любой-язык, code-style

Я знаю, что сохранять переменную целесообразно, если она часто используется дальше:

```
int speed = car.getSpeed();
backgroundAnimator.setSpeed(speed);
speedometer.setSpeed(speed);
```

Но что, если переменная используется далее лишь один раз, но чтобы её получить надо совершить долгий путь?

```
int speed = getScene().getCar().getBlahBlah...().getSpeed();
blah().blah.ichoblah().blaaaah(car, speed);
```

Не буду же я в таком случае объединять код ради того, чтобы избежать лишней переменной?

Comment: Это зачастую улучшает читаемость кода. Значит - это хорошо. А современные компилиторы большинства языков выкинут ненужную переменную, следовательно снижения производительности и лишнего расхода памяти не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если говорить о стиле и поддержке кода, то использование переменной (т.е. создание ячейки памяти и вынос этого длинного инициализирующего выражение в отдельную строку) повышает читабельность и понимаемость кода, а также, в случае апдейта конкретного фрагмента кода эта переменная может быть использована повторно (если только Вы не можете гарантировать, что такого точно не будет).

Можно это длинное выражение вставить в функцию в некоторых случаях, например, когда функция принимает rvalue. Или Вам надо сэкономить на создании переменной, хотя это не сильно отразится на всей картине.

Вот что говорится об использовании такой переменной:

> Каждая переменная должна объявляться в самом глубоком блоке, который окружает все возможные места использования переменной.

Также можете обратить внимание на эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/172091/), в частности, правила 61 и 64. Обращаю внимание, что эти правила относятся к булевым переменным, но идеология та же:

```
bool isFinished = (elementNo < 0) || (elementNo > maxElement);
bool isRepeatedEntry = elementNo == lastElement;

if (isFinished || isRepeatedEntry) 
{
    ...
}

// NOT:
if ((elementNo < 0) || (elementNo > maxElement)||
    elementNo == lastElement) 
{
    ...
}
```

> Задание булевых переменных для выражений приведёт к самодокументированию программы. Конструкцию будет легче читать, отлаживать и поддерживать.

```
File* fileHandle = open(fileName, "w");

if (!fileHandle) 
{
    ...
}

// NOT:
if (!(fileHandle = open(fileName, "w"))) 
{
    ...
}
```

> Исполняемые выражения в условиях усложняют читаемость. Особенно это касается новичков в С/С++.

**Примечание**: Не помню, какой автор писал об этом (полагаю, многие), но есть рекомендация заменять глобальные переменные функциями типа `get()`. Создание функции-геттера получится применить и в рассматриваемой ситуации. Можно этот длинный вызов обернуть в другой вызываемый объект (функцию, лямбду) с коротким именем, чтобы он возвращал требуемое значение. Такое применимо, если запрашиваемое значение может изменяться, пока Ваш код работает, а запрашиваемое значение обновляется (например, в другом потоке). С переменной придется обновлять значение, заново вызывая эти спагетти.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал сюда вынести цитатами эти пункты 61 и 64

Comment: @АлексейШиманский секунду, еще не закончил ;)

Comment: Собственно, так я и думал. Спасибо за ответ )

Comment: @Flippy сейчас вспомнил еще один вариант, напишу в ответ, рассмотрите.

Comment: Очень радует что я так и делаю как в коде из этих советов. Я как только вижу внутренние скобки, хочу вынести одно выражение наружу. Правда очень долго придумываю переменным имена, но это уже совсем другая история

Comment: @Flippy история про долгое придумывание имен переменным - история не только у Вас ;)